# Catch exception thrown while task execution in anonymous method

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, system.reactive

I have a code similar to this :

```
class A
{
    public Action<int, int> OnAddition;

    public int Add(int val1, int val2)
    {
        if (OnAddition != null)
        {
            OnAddition(val1, val2);
        }

        return val1 + val2;
    }
}

class B
{
    A a = new A();

    public B()
    {
        a.OnAddition = (v1, v2) =>
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Adding {0} and {1}", v1, v2);
                throw new Exception("Blah");
            });
        };
    }

    public int Add(int val1, int val2)
    {
        return a.Add(val1, val2);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            B b = new B();

            Console.WriteLine(b.Add(1, 7));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

I have no control over the classes `A` and `B` and the problem is that when 
`throw new Exception("Blah");` happens my code is not able to catch the exception.

How can my code catch that Exception ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. If you can't change the code for these classes you can't **catch** that exception.

You can however be notified about it by subscribing to the `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` event that will be raised when the GC collects that task.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have no control over the classes, there's no possible way for you to catch the exception.  You're throwing the exception *after you've already finished invoking the event*, so you've already (at least potentially) left the `try` block by the time the event is thrown.  The event would need to be specifically designed to support handling errors of asynchronous method handlers to be able to handle such an exception.